# Move Specific Elements

Tags: php, css, wordpress, positioning

I'm currently building a site using WordPress. I'm trying to layout a listview for the products page with CSS but I am experiencing a couple of problems. The code behind these elements are within the WordPress files so I'd rather not touch those if possible.

What I'm trying to do is move "MSDS" next to the title as it was below the title before. I've set it to relative position and moved it using top and right pixel values.

Example 1
[image: Example 1]

Example 2
[image: Example 2]

My first problem is that if you look at Example 1. I have positioned "MSDS" next to that specific title but when you look at Example 2, it has a shorter product name but the positioning of "MSDS" is the same therefore it looks silly. How do I go about fixing this?

My second problem may be fixed if the first is fixed but on a maximised window, the layout looks fine but when resized to a smaller window then the window covers "MSDS" but the title looks fine as it wraps so it's viewable on the page.

I'm not entirely sure where to look or what specific things I should be looking for to find a fix for this. So any help would be much appreciated. The code below is what I used to reposition the "MSDS"

```
.product-list .product-thumb .description {
position: relative;
bottom: 26px;
left: 290px;
width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try using `:after`, can you show the styles of that element, so we can help you

Comment: In addition to what @Paulie_D pointed out: please don't link to third-party hosts for relevant content. Include code, and if you absolutely have to, screenshots in the question itself. Links can die, at which point this question simply doesn't make any sense to anyone anymore

Comment: _“The code behind these elements are within the WordPress files so I'd rather not touch those if possible”_ – why not, that is what a theming system is _for_. Anyway, it might be enough to make the element that holds the title and the MSDS one display as inline(-block)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `:after` for these things

These should help.

Add these in your stylesheet to

```
.product-list .product-thumb .description:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "MSDS";
  color: blue;
}
```

You can style the element accordingly then

Comment: The title is `<h3>` while the MSDS is a div class `<div class="description">`. The "MSDS" contains a specific link to each product so I can't really hard code that unless I make a number of contents for each product. How do I go about using the `:after` with this in mind?

Comment: Could you please provide full code, so i can clearly see things and help you out

Comment: Here's a draft version of the site I'm currently messing with [link](https://4candles.uk/product-category/candle-making-fragrance-oils/escentscia-us-style-oil/). The CSS above is mainly what I'm working with as the other elements such as the title is within the WordPress files and i'm assuming I can still get what I want to achieve without touching those files.

Comment: The pages are currently messing up and not displaying in list view. Hang on a second

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for position: relative and position: absolute i think.

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/r5rnyh3y/1/

```
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.title a {
  position:absolute;
  right: -100%;
  margin-right: -10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```